# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-5})$ has no power integral basis

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

By a power integral basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ one means that $\exists \alpha\in K$ s.t. $\{1,\alpha ,\alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^{n-1}\}$ forms an integral basis of $K$.

The question is whether $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-5})$ has no power integral basis.

I believe the answer is no, and I tried to use *Dedekind's Theorem* (Theorem 1 in [this](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf) lecnote) to prove it. Take $(3)$, a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, consider its decomposition in $K$. But as I cannot find such a generator of power integral basis, how can I decompose the non-exist minimal polynomial modulo 3, and deduce a contradiction?

Comment: Hint: $p=3$ splits in both $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$, so splits in $K$, so there are 4 distinct prime ideals in $K$ lying over $p$. If $K$ had a power basis, Dedekind's theorem would imply there are at most $p=3$ distinct prime ideals lying over $p$, contradiction.

Comment: Are these prime ideals $(1\pm \sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-2}\pm\sqrt{-5})$? I think I could complete this proof with the help of your hint. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $3=(1+\sqrt{-2})(1-\sqrt{-2})=(\sqrt{-2}+\sqrt{-5})(\sqrt{-2}-\sqrt{-5})$.

Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\pi_1=(1+\sqrt{-2}, \sqrt{-2}+\sqrt{-5}), \\ &\pi_2=(1-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{-2}+\sqrt{-5}), \\ &\pi_3=(1+\sqrt{-2}, \sqrt{-2}-\sqrt{-5}), \\ &\pi_4=(1-\sqrt{-2}, \sqrt{-2}-\sqrt{-5}).
\end{aligned}
$$
By direct calculate one knows that $\pi_i\neq\pi_j,\forall i\neq j$; $\pi_1\pi_2=\pi_1\cap\pi_2=(\sqrt{-2}+\sqrt{-5})$; $\pi_3\pi_4=\pi_3\cap\pi_4=(\sqrt{-2}-\sqrt{-5})$.

Hence $(3)=\pi_1\pi_2\pi_3\pi_4$. Moreover, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-5}) : \mathbb{Q}]=4$, thus by $\sum e_i f_i=[K : \mathbb{Q}]$ in prime decomposition one knows $\pi_i$ are prime ideals, contradicting the fact that there are only 3 monic degree 1 polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$.